# Saving object as variable inside activiti

Tags: spring-mvc, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn.io

We are revamping a big enterprise application which has more business workflows. We are using activiti bpm with spring MVC. Currently we are saving the required variables for workflow inside execution individually. My idea is to create object for each workflow and save the object as variable inside activiti execution instead of individual variables.

For example for the job application workflow I will have JobRequest object which have all the requested details like approvers, interviewers, candidate profiles, current status, etc., I will save this object as variable inside activiti. Whenever I need I will just get the object back and show the needed info on the web page. It will be hassle free than maintaining all those information on separate tables and getting the reference alone from activiti.

Is this good approach?

Still I have some concerns on my approach.

1. If suppose later we add additional fields to the Class. Then how to
   handle the history object variables. (In the above example we are
   adding additional field under JobRequest.class).
2. In our current approach if some values really needs to be verified I
   can connect to the activiti database and able to see. Because the
   variables are saved individually.

Any valuable suggestion?

Comment: When dealing with complex datatypes, such as application forms, contracts and such, you can use a custom datatypes or, as an alternative, use a process variable that holds an external reference. This reference can be a simple I'd or, even better, an URI than can be used to fetch the external entity. Using custom variables keeps everything tightly coupled and allows for easy data retrieval using activiti's apis. A reference usually helps with integration with other systems.

Comment: I agree with Philippe, For complex variables that you want to maintain I would create java Entities and save the data using JPA, then pass the reference ID through the process and retrieve the attribute when you need it. This keeps your process variable lightweight and means you externalize your system of record. If you need to track data changes for governance/audit, you can still do this by firing events using the activiti event framework.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestions @PhilippeSevestre